# How can compare values of two arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, function

I want to compare one array values in another. Following are two different arrays.

```
$a = Array (9,39,40,41);

$b = Array ( [0] => 38 [1] => 1 [2] => 36 [3] => 37 [4] => 9 [5] => 2 );
```

I want to check if `$a` values are in `$b`. Condition Should true when `$a` all values are exist in `$b`.

```
if($a in $b ){ echo 'true'; }
```

Comment: Use [array_intersect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php), and [count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)

Comment: @MarkBaker thanks for suggestion, I'm going to try

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) like so

```
$intersection = array_intersect($a, $b);
$ok = (count(($intersection) === count($a));
```